# Teradata SQL: Group by when summing over rows unbounded

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I am a little confused about how the sum over rows unbounded function works.

I am running the following code to get the following output:

```
select
policy_id,
incurred_date,
paid_date,
row_number () over (partition by policy_agreement_id, incurred_date order by paid_date) as row_num
from table1
qualify row_num = 1

policy_id | incurred_date | paid_date | row_num

111 | 01/01/2019 | 01/10/2019 | 1
222 | 01/01/2019 | 01/10/2019 | 1
333 | 01/01/2019 | 01/11/2019 | 1
444 | 01/01/2019 | 01/11/2019 | 1
etc..
```

What I want to do is getting a running total of the policy_ids for each incurred_date as paid_date increases.

When I run the following code, I am not getting what I want:

```
select
incurred_date,
paid_date,
sum(row_num) over (partition by incurred_date order by paid_date rows unbounded preceding)
from (
    select
    policy_id,
    incurred_date,
    paid_date,
    row_number () over (partition by policy_agreement_id, incurred_date order by paid_date) as row_num
    from table1
    qualify row_num = 1
    ) sub
group by 1,2, row_num

incurred_date | paid_date | pol_count
01/01/2019 | 01/10/2019 | 1
01/01/2019 | 01/11/2019 | 2

Desired output:

incurred_date | paid_date | pol_count
01/01/2019 | 01/10/2019 | 2
01/01/2019 | 01/11/2019 | 4
```

I understand this is probably because row_num is in the group by and it is always equal to one, however I am unable to run my code without it there.  I am able to get the desired output through other means, but I am curious as to why row_num needs to be in the group by or if I am just not seeing something that I am missing.

Comment: When you do an aggregation (`GROUP BY`) you need to include all of the non-aggregate columns in your query in the `GROUP BY` clause.  I think this is why you need to include `row_num`, since it's being used as an expression in a window function (`OVER(...)`) and not in an aggregate function.

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  When I look at my code, it feels like row_num is being used as an aggregate function in not the window function.  It is in the SUM() and not in the OVER() function, so I'm still not understanding why it has to be included in the group by.

Comment: By specifying the `OVER( ...)` clause with your `SUM()`, you're converting it from a straight aggregate into a window function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are seeing this behavior because you have a window function and an aggregate function in the same query.  The aggregate function (`GROUP BY`) will be executed before the window function (`SUM() OVER(...)`).  So, going by your example, you will never get a `pol_count` value greater than 2, since there are only two unique `paid_date` values for each `incurred_date`.

If you just want to get a running total of `policy_id`s for each `incurred_date`, try using a cumulative sum:

```sql
  SELECT 
    src.incurred_date, 
    src.paid_date, 
    SUM(src.pol_count) OVER(
      PARTITION BY src.incurred_date, src.paid_date 
      ORDER BY src.paid_date ASC
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW -- Cumulative sum
    )
  FROM (
    SELECT incurred_date, paid_date, COUNT(*) AS pol_count -- Get counts
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY incurred_date, paid_date
  ) src
```

This assumes that `table1` stores one row per `policy_id`.

Comment: Sorry when I wrote the code earlier I left out that I had used rows unbounded preceding in the sum over statement.  (must've forgot when I was typing it over here, I have edited it in).  I'm still not necessarily seeing the difference in your code versus mine.  Wouldn't you still need a group by after ) src because you are using SUM in the select statement

Comment: No. The PARTITION BY clause in a windowed aggregate serves the same purpose as the GROUP BY clause for non-windowed aggregates. Generally I would recommend not having both types at the same query level; nest one within the other as in this answer, to be sure you are getting the desired order of operations and desired result.